# Issues with BCM43142 driver on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wireless, 20.04, broadcom

Just installed the new ubuntu 20.04, Used to have the same problem with on Linux Mint earlier not sure it was solved. Checked with iwconfig the link quality and signal level keeps on fluctuating. Using bcmwl-kernel-source as the primary driver.

Comment: Some fluctuation is normal with radio signals. It will never be a constant strength. Is it preventing you from browsing or downloading? How wide is the variance?

Comment: Using usb wifi adapter it do remains constant. While continuous usage it do not fluctuates, but if left idle for some time I do see it fluctuating. Not the case in windows though, so I thought maybe I am lacking some drivers.

Comment: Again, it's a radio signal and some fluctuation *is going to* happen. I just ran mine ten times and it bounces between 52/70 and 54/70 all within the ~30 seconds it took to run the commands. How wide is your variance? Is it affecting your ability to browse, to download, or?

Comment: As I mentioned, I didn't observed this variance with a usb wifi receiver. It doesn't affect that much but sometimes it results in disconnection or slow response.